# Sporadic (Authentication??) Failures and Expirations in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, scala, docker, reactivemongo, akka-http

I have a few problems with connecting to my MongoDB replica set.
I have created a mongodb admin user for reading and writing. I can log into the mongo shell on the terminal successfully, and the session has never expired.

In my scala application I am running akka-http with reactivemongo 0.11.9 and MongoDB 3.2.1 with the mongo replication set inside Docker containers on 3 separate servers with persistent storage to their respective hosts. I am authenticating the mongo connection when the server starts up.

About 60% of the time it works temporarily (40% it fails to authenticate on start) and after 5-20 minutes, my connections are no longer authenticated or the connections have died and cannot reconnect. I have not found anything anywhere about keeping the authentication open longer or why the connection would just drop and not recover, and seeing as how the authentication is at the connection level it should remain authenticated as long as the connection exists.

Here is my mongo connection object:

```
class MongodbDataStore(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) {

 var driver1 = new reactivemongo.api.MongoDriver
 var mongoOptions = new MongoConnectionOptions(nbChannelsPerNode = 5,
                                               connectTimeoutMS = 300000, 
                                               authMode = ScramSha1Authentication)
 var counter = 0
 val dbName = "admin"
 val userName = "name"
 val password = "password"
 val credentials = List(Authenticate(dbName, userName, password))
 var connection3 = Array(driver1.connection(List("X.X.X.X","X.X.X.X","X.X.X.X"), mongoOptions, authentications = credentials))

 def getdb: BSONCollection = {
   counter = counter + 1
   val database: reactivemongo.api.DB = connection3(0).db("database")
   database.collection[BSONCollection]("collection")
 }

}
```

Once the authentication expires I get this error:

```
reactivemongo.core.errors.GenericDriverException: MongoError['socket disconnected']
18:23:58.655 [reactivemongo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] ERROR reactivemongo.core.actors.MongoDBSystem - The primary is unavailable, is there a network problem?
18:23:58.655 [reactivemongo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] ERROR reactivemongo.core.actors.MongoDBSystem - The primary is unavailable, is there a network problem?
18:23:59.092 [ReactiveKafka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] ERROR reactivemongo.api.Failover2 - Got an error, no more attempts to do. Completing with a failure...
reactivemongo.core.actors.Exceptions$PrimaryUnavailableException$: MongoError['No primary node is available!']
    at reactivemongo.core.actors.Exceptions$PrimaryUnavailableException$.<clinit>(actors.scala) ~[reactivemongo_2.11-0.11.9.jar:0.11.9]
    at reactivemongo.api.Failover2.reactivemongo$api$Failover2$$isRetryable(api.scala:139) ~[reactivemongo_2.11-0.11.9.jar:0.11.9]
    at reactivemongo.api.Failover2$$anonfun$reactivemongo$api$Failover2$$send$2.apply(api.scala:117) [reactivemongo_2.11-0.11.9.jar:0.11.9]
    at reactivemongo.api.Failover2$$anonfun$reactivemongo$api$Failover2$$send$2.apply(api.scala:116) [reactivemongo_2.11-0.11.9.jar:0.11.9]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:399) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:?]
[ERROR] [02/17/2016 18:23:59.093] [ReactiveKafka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(ReactiveKafka)] Error during processing of request HttpRequest(HttpMethod(POST),http://127.0.0.1:9001/user_login,List(Host: 127.0.0.1:9001, Connection: keep-alive, Cache-Control: no-cache, Origin: chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop, User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36, Postman-Token:..., Accept: */*, Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, Accept-Language: en-US, en;q=0.8),HttpEntity.Strict(application/json,ByteString(32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 123, 34, 107, 101, 121, 34, 58, 34, 117, 83, 101, 68, 84, 111, 67, 97, 76, 108, 77, 69, 111, 78, 109, 89, 67, 69, 108, 108, 80, 104, 79, 110, 51, 34, 44, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 112, 104, 111, 110, 101, 78, 117, 109, 98, 101, 114, 34, 58, 34, 49, 55, 55, 50, 49, 50, 52, 56, 51, 52, 49, 34, 44, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 112, 97, 115, 115, 119, 111, 114, 100, 34, 58, 34)... and [16] more),HttpProtocol(HTTP/1.1))
reactivemongo.core.actors.Exceptions$PrimaryUnavailableException$: MongoError['No primary node is available!']
    at reactivemongo.core.actors.Exceptions$PrimaryUnavailableException$.<clinit>(actors.scala)
    at reactivemongo.api.Failover2.reactivemongo$api$Failover2$$isRetryable(api.scala:139)
    at reactivemongo.api.Failover2$$anonfun$reactivemongo$api$Failover2$$send$2.apply(api.scala:117)
    at reactivemongo.api.Failover2$$anonfun$reactivemongo$api$Failover2$$send$2.apply(api.scala:116)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:399)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Is there a setting somewhere I am missing about expiration of authentication? Is it possible by mongo connections are failing do to another reason and if the connections are failing for another reason, why won't it recover and find the primary to write to? Has anyone else seen or had this issue or one similar?

Comment: I don't see the authentication error?

Comment: @cchantep That is also the error that I get when I put in improper authentication credentials. It cannot find the primaries to write to because it loses the authentication. Before I added authentication I never got this error or any error like it.

Comment: Quite unclear, why using unproper credentials?

Comment: To test the errors. The credentials in this particular example are the correct credentials.

Comment: If the credentials are ok, you do have a network issue. Check [examples](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/tutorial/connect-database.html#more-examples).

Comment: @cchantep while that would be true for most people, it was not true in this case. It was due to that particular version of reactivemongo not working with the newest mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the error was due to ReactiveMongo not supporting the newest MongoDB. Once ReactiveMongo released an update everything worked properly.

0.11.9 does not work with MongoDb 3.2.1

0.11.10 does work with MongoDb 3.2.1